# submit form email link -- weird email entries

Tags: forms, submit, html-email, form-submit

I'm using HTML currently to create a submit form and link it to an email address. Wondering how I can get rid of the strange appearance of the text (name=, email=, message=) after the client fills out the form, clicks the submit button, and is taken to gmail:

Here's the code:

```
        <form class="contact-form" action="mailto:d5nguyen@gmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
            <div class="row">
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" required>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" required>
            </div>    
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col span-1-of-2">
                    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your message" ></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col span-2-of-3">
                    <input type="submit" value="send">
                    <input type="reset" value="reset">
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

I'd like to figure out a way to 1) have an input area in the form for the email subject line and 2) remove "email=", "name=", and "message=" so that it's not visible in the email.

Comment: What happened when you removed `email` from `name="email"`?

Comment: I figured it out. so I think the 'method="post"' is what puts the markup in the email. when I removed it, the markup was not there.